# Get-MsalToken: The property 'Authority' cannot be found on this object

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-msal

I am creating dashboard with Powershell Universal (https://docs.powershelluniversal.com/userinterfaces/dashboards) and I am trying to get an access token in order to connect to MS Graph. I am using the command `Get-MsalToken` (part of the MSAL.PS module) to get an access token. The code I am running is below:

```
$Params = @{
    ClientId = $Credential.UserName
    ClientSecret = $Credential.Password
    TenantId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ForceRefresh = $true
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
}
$AccessToken = (Get-MsalToken @Params).AccessToken
```

When running the above code on the command line using Powershell 7, it works fine. However when the dashboard runs the same command on Powershell 7, it returns this error message:

`Get-MsalToken: The property 'Authority' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.`

The module MSAL.PS is on version 4.37.00 on both my local instance and on the server where the dashboard is running from. For the most part I am unable to replicate the error on the command line on either my machine or on the server, and the command works perfectly. I was able to reproduce the error locally on my machine's command line after connecting to other services and then running `Get-MsalToken`, but trying this a second time is getting the access token correctly, so I am unable to accurately reproduce the error on the command line. The dashboard however is consistent with this error. Running an automated script from the server also does not produce the error.

I did see a forum on github about this same issue, but there is no clear resolution. I did see people recommending commenting out some lines from the source code, but given that they recommend commenting out a line for TenantID, which I am using for the connection, I am not in favor of doing that. The forum can be found here: https://github.com/AzureAD/MSAL.PS/issues/45

I was just wondering if anybody else has run into this issue or knows of a solution or alternative. Thanks!

Comment: I recently ran into this issue with a few of my scripts using the `Microsoft.Graph` and `ExchangeOnlineManagement` modules alongside the `MSAL.PS` module. For me, the fix was to ensure that my `Import-Module` statements loaded the `MSAL.PS` module before the Exchange or MS Graph ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NiMux stated above, the solution is to simply import the `MSAL.PS` module before importing anything else. At the top of the main page of my code I simply added `Import-Module -Name MSAL.PS -Force` and I got it to work properly. Even though the module was already installed and imported, it needs to be imported before anything else.

Hopefully this helps somebody else with this issue in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the AzureCloudInstance parameter worked for me. This is a more reliable fix than importing the module first or changing source code.

```
$Params = @{
    ClientId = $Credential.UserName
    ClientSecret = $Credential.Password
    TenantId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ForceRefresh = $true
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
    AzureCloudInstance = 1
}
```

[Here is a link to how the AzureCloudInstance parameter works.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.azurecloudinstance?view=msal-dotnet-latest&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet-preview)
It's in C# but it translates to PowerShell too. I put 1 because it's the most general but the value might depend on where your organization is located.